# Deriving the Spinor Completeness Relation without using a Representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices, trace

Reference: DAMTP [problem set 3, question 5](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/oh3.pdf) but ignore the spinor solutions given.

To preface, this has taken up 1 entire day and a further 2 afternoons of work so I will just list the most promising attempts rather than clutter half a notebook !

Given the relations for the spinors, $u(\mathbf{p},\pm\tfrac{1}{2})$ and $v(\mathbf{p},\pm\tfrac{1}{2})$ as,

$$
(\not p - m)u(\mathbf{p},s) = 0\qquad
(\not p + m)v(\mathbf{p},s) = 0
$$
$$
\bar{u}(\mathbf{p},s)u(\mathbf{p},r) = 2m\delta_{sr}\qquad
\bar{v}(\mathbf{p},s)v(\mathbf{p},r) = -2m\delta_{sr}\qquad
\bar{u}(\mathbf{p},s)v(\mathbf{p},s) = 0
$$

I am trying to prove the following,

$$
\tag{1}
\Lambda_+ = \sum_{s} u(\mathbf{p},s)\bar{u}(\mathbf{p},s) = \not p + m
$$
$$
\tag{2}
\Lambda_+ = \sum_{s} v(\mathbf{p},s)\bar{v}(\mathbf{p},s) = \not p - m
$$

Choosing a representation is too easy and considered cheating. All the information other than trace identities is given above. I believe the same goes for using the spin projection operator.

### Attempts

I have shown linear independence in a previous exercise from the same information, so we can assume that $u(\mathbf{p},\pm\tfrac{1}{2})$ and $v(\mathbf{p},\pm\tfrac{1}{2})$ are linearly independent.

1. Adding (1)+(2) ... **result**: $0$ as $u\bar{u} = (u\bar{u})^{\dagger} = \bar{u}u$ and by the relations we get $4m - 4m = 0$ and no useful information is gained
2. Subtracting (1)-(2) ... **result**: $8m$ as above
3. Acting on (1), (2) from the right with $(\not p + m)$ from the right ... **result** $\pm 4m$ by $ u \bar{u} \not p u$
4. Acting on (1), (2) from the right with $u,v,\bar{u},\bar{v}$ ... **result** same as 3.

In fact every attempt I try just gives me a result with $m$ which gives me reason to believe that there is something fundamentally wrong in my understanding.

### Potential Issue

I can 'force' the result by just using the Dirac equation $(\not p + m)u(\mathbf{p},r) = 0$ to equate $\not p$ to $m$ but I don't think this is what I am supposed to be doing, although I cannot see any other way!

The reason I do not like this is because it doesn't force me to limit myself (I believe) to just changing one $2m \to \pm \not p$. I feel if I were to do this I need some condition that prevents me from picking both as $\not p$ to obtain $\Lambda_+ = 2\not p$ for example.

Comment: See Srednicki, http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf, paragraph around Eq.(38.23), pg.243 (start on pg.240).

Comment: I have Srednicki's book but I discarded this method because it relies on a representation as such, since we are assuming we know $-\not p = \gamma^0 m$. I am beginning to think that this is probably the only way to solve this properly and that the question I posed myself is too contrasined.

Comment: Not really, see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rest frame $\not p \rightarrow - m \gamma^0$ and
$$
(\not p - m)u(\mathbf{p},s) = 0 \;\; \rightarrow \;\; (I + \gamma^0) u(\mathbf{0},s) = 0 \\
{\bar u}(\mathbf{p},s)(\not p - m) = 0 \;\; \rightarrow \;\; {\bar u}(\mathbf{0},s) (I + \gamma^0)  = 0 \\
(\not p + m)v(\mathbf{p},s) = 0 \;\; \rightarrow \;\; (I - \gamma^0) v(\mathbf{0},s) = 0 \\
{\bar v}(\mathbf{p},s)(\not p + m) = 0 \;\; \rightarrow \;\; {\bar v}(\mathbf{p},s)(I - \gamma^0) = 0
$$
So regardless of representation $u(\mathbf{0},s)$ and $v(\mathbf{0},s)$ become right eigenvectors of $\gamma^0$, while ${\bar u}(\mathbf{0},s)$ and ${\bar v}(\mathbf{0},s)$ become left eigenvectors.

This gives closure relationships for both the identity $I$ and $\gamma^0$ in terms of $u{\bar u}$ and $v{\bar v}$ outer products, wherefrom similar closure relations for $I \pm \gamma^0$ follow immediately.

Boost back to an arbitrary frame and you are left with the required relations for $\not p \pm m$.

On a second thought, just notice that $u(\mathbf{p},s)$, $v(\mathbf{p},s)$ are right eigenvectors of $\not p$, and ${\bar u}(\mathbf{p},s)$, ${\bar v}(\mathbf{p},s)$ are left eigenvectors. Build the expression of $\not p$ on the $\mathbf{p}$ eigensubspace in terms of $u{\bar u}$, $v{\bar v}$, and the corresponding closure relation for the eigensubspace projector. Then use those to extract expressions for $\not p \pm m$. No need to boost anywhere!

Comment: I had previously thought that $\not p \rightarrow - m \gamma^0$ was also cheating that's why I thought it was impossible!

Comment: Come to think about it, you don't even need to deal with $\gamma^0$ :)

Comment: I'll discuss this with a course mate and see if his method is any improvement before accepting. +1 in the meantime thanks :) and I will come back with a reply later if you are still interested.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0703214.pdf see section 5.3, page 15

Comment: Awesome, wasn't aware of this ref. But it's definitely great. Thanks!

Comment: accepted the answer since it seems that explicitly or implicitly one must write some kind of tensor and treat certain parts differently. The simplest and most general version being as you state with taking $\mathbf{p}=0$. There is no way that this is possible at an algebra level that I have found as all "claims" as such just skip the line of explicit working in which they write down a vector and fix the 3-momentum as zero